# Backbone.js template error with coffeescript and eco templating language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, backbone.js, coffeescript, eco

***Solved:***

I have a backbone(0.9.2) written in  coffeescript as follows

```
class Animal.Views.Cats extends Backbone.View
 template: JST['animals/cats']
 ...
 ...
 render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template())
  this
```

With this coffeescript code, when i execute in browser,
i get the following error in console

> **Property template of object <#cat> is not a function**

I am using eco template with rails 3.1 backend
where am i going wrong?

**solution:**

the problem was a deeply nested template file structure

> template: JST['mammals/animals/cats'] fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate, if you have a directory structure like this:

```
app/assets/templates/namespace/animals/cats.jst.eco
```

You need to include your namespace when referencing your template:

- Will **not** work: `JST['animals/cats']`
- Will work: `JST['namespace/animals/cats']`

Answer (score 1):

in your code 'template' is not defined as a function but as a attribute.

try

```
template: -> JST['animals/cats']
```

ie, insert the function arrow '->'

or, if you do not want that to be a function, then drop the parentheses after @template

```
$(@el).html @template
```

Comment: with template: -> the actual template file doesn't get picked up

Comment: so does it work if you drop the parentheses and treat template as an attribute? or does the 'animals/cats' template not actually exist?